# Geonetwork overlapping labels

Tags: labeling, xml, geonetwork

the labels in GeoNetwork are defined as:

```xml
<element name="gmd:codeSpace" context="gmd:RD_Identifier">
  <label>Namespace</label>
</element>
```

but the problem is we also have a Regulation Source which is saved in the metadata in a ***gmd:codeSpace*** tag and if we create a new element for that it gets ignored since both have the same name and the same context (***gmd:RD_Identifier***).

Is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the full XPath as `context` if they have a different one for each element. For example

```xml
    <element name="gmd:codeSpace" context="/gmd:MD_Metadata/gmd:referenceSystemInfo/gmd:MD_ReferenceSystem/gmd:referenceSystemIdentifier/gmd:RS_Identifier/gmd:codeSpace">
       <label>Namespace</label>
    </element>
```

```xml
    <element name="gmd:codeSpace" context="/gmd:MD_Metadata/other/path/to/gmd:RS_Identifier/gmd:codeSpace">
       <label>Regulation Source</label>
    </element>
```